# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in JSON format

Tags: c#, json, ajax, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to get data from my database using AJAX and put that data in my jQuery FullCalendar. though when trying to get the data I get an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [(JSON object)]

when I `console.log(doc)` I get a correct JSON object which I validated using [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

I made a question yesterday about a different error but the same script so [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48908865/unexpected-token-u-in-json-at-position-0-when-parsing-data/48909161?noredirect=1#comment84825535_48909161) is some additional information to see what I have tried and how I got to this point.

This is the output of the `console.log(obj)`:

```
[  
{  
  "id":1,
  "title":"K. Keesen",
  "desc":"zelf ziek gemeld",
  "start":"2-2-2018 13:00:00",
  "end":"5-2-2018 13:00:00",
  "user":15,
  "melding":1
  },
  {  
  "id":3,
  "title":"K. Keesen",
  "desc":null,
  "start":"2-2-2018 13:00:00",
  "end":"5-2-2019 13:00:00",
  "user":15,
  "melding":1
  },
  {  
  "id":5,
  "title":"K. Keesen",
  "desc":null,
  "start":"14-2-2018 08:30:00",
  "end":"",
  "user":15,
  "melding":1
  },
  {  
  "id":6,
  "title":"K. Keesen",
  "desc":"srgsrgrgdrgdrgd",
  "start":"7-2-2018 08:30:00",
  "end":"",
  "user":38,
  "melding":13
  },
  {  
  "id":7,
  "title":"T. test",
  "desc":null,
  "start":"14-2-2018 08:30:00",
  "end":"21-2-2018 17:00:00",
  "user":63,
  "melding":10
  },
  {  
  "id":8,
  "title":"K. Keesen",
  "desc":null,
  "start":"16-2-2018 08:30:00",
  "end":"23-2-2018 17:00:00",
  "user":28,
  "melding":14
  },
  {  
  "id":9,
  "title":"K. Keesen",
  "desc":null,
  "start":"14-2-2018 08:30:00",
  "end":"",
  "user":33,
  "melding":12
  },
  {  
  "id":10,
  "title":"K. Keesen",
  "desc":"fvghbj",
  "start":"22-2-2018 08:30:00",
  "end":"",
  "user":15,
  "melding":11
  },
  {  
  "id":11,
  "title":"K. Keesen",
  "desc":null,
  "start":"15-2-2018 08:30:00",
  "end":"22-2-2018 17:00:00",
  "user":15,
  "melding":1
  },
  {  
  "id":12,
  "title":"K. Keesen",
  "desc":null,
  "start":"23-2-2018 08:30:00",
  "end":"",
  "user":15,
  "melding":1
  },
  {  
  "id":13,
  "title":"K. Keesen",
  "desc":"Test take #25",
  "start":"7-2-2018 08:30:00",
  "end":"23-2-2018 17:00:00",
  "user":15,
  "melding":1
  },
  {  
  "id":14,
  "title":"K. Keesen",
  "desc":null,
  "start":"8-2-2018 08:30:00",
  "end":"",
  "user":15,
  "melding":1
  }
]
```

I'm not very good at AJAX so I bet there are mistakes that I can't see, this is my script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        GenerateCalendar();

        function GenerateCalendar() {
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
                theme: true,
                header: {
                    left: "prev,next today",
                    center: "title",
                    right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
                },

                defaultView: 'month',
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true,
                events: function (start, end, callback) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",    //WebMethods will not allow GET
                        url: '@Url.Action("List/medewerker_melding")',   //url of a webmethod - example below
                        data: "",  //completely take out 'data:' line if you don't want to pass to webmethod - Important to also change webmethod to not accept any parameters
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (doc) {
                            var events = [];   //javascript event object created here
                            var obj = JSON.parse(doc);  //.net returns json wrapped in "doc"
                            console.log(obj); //Shows a correct JSON format in the console
                            //jQuery.parse.JSON(obj); //This gives an error: Cannot read property 'JSON' of undefined
                            $.each(doc, function (index, obj) {
                                events.push({
                                    title: obj.title,
                                    start: obj.start,
                                    end: obj.end
                                });
                            });
                            callback(events);

                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', events, true);
                        }
                    });
                },

                select: function (start, end) {
                    var start = moment(start).format();
                    var end = moment(end).format();
                    $('#startDate').val(start);
                    $('#endDate').val(end);
                    $('#eventModal').modal();
                    if ($('#eventModal')) {
                        $(".meldingForm").submit(function () {
                        });
                    }
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                },
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here's the controller that it sends the request to:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("List")]
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        temphrmEntities db = new temphrmEntities();
        List<medewerker_melding> eventList = db.medewerker_melding.ToList();

        // Select events and return datetime as sortable XML Schema style.
        var events = from ev in eventList
                     select new
                     {
                         id = ev.ID,
                         title = ev.medewerker.voorvoegsel + ". " + ev.medewerker.achternaam,
                         desc = ev.Omschrijving,
                         start = ev.datum_van.ToString(),
                         end = ev.datum_tot.ToString(),
                         user = ev.medewerkerID,
                         melding = ev.meldingID
                     };

        // Serialize to JSON string.
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        String json = jss.Serialize(events);
        Debug.WriteLine("Json:"+json);
        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

and for those who would like to try and reproduce the issue, here's my HTML and some additional script:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="eventModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Creëer agenda item</h3>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <span id="verplicht">Velden met <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i> bent u verplicht in te vullen</span>
        <form class="meldingForm" role="form" action="@Url.Action("Create", "medewerker_melding")" method="post">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p><label for="werknemer">Werknemer:</label>@Html.DropDownList("medewerkerID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control ddL" })</p>
                <p><label for="titel">Titel:</label>@Html.DropDownList("meldingID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control ddL" })</p>
                <p><label for="start"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Start:</label><input name="startDate" id="startDate" type="date" class="form-control" onmousedown='return false;' readonly required /><input name="start" id="start" class="form-control time" required /></p>
                <p><label for="end">Eind:</label><input name="endDate" type="date" class="form-control" /><input name="end" id="end" class="form-control time" /></p>
                <p><label for="Omschrijving">Omschrijving:</label><textarea type="text" name="Omschrijving" id="Omschrijving" class="Omschrijving form-control" placeholder="Omschrijving" maxlength="200"></textarea></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            //zorgt ervoor dat de KendoTimePicker de juiste opties weergeeft.
            $('#start').kendoTimePicker({
                format: "HH:mm",
                min: "8:00",
                max: "17:30",
                value: "8:30",
                interval: 15
            });

            $('#end').kendoTimePicker({
                format: "HH:mm",
                min: "8:00",
                max: "17:30",
                value: "17:00",
                interval: 15
            });
        })
```

**EDIT**

I changed a line in my ajax to make an object out of the doc string, I accidently left that in there. now the output is this:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8acze0zg/) (it wouldnt go in a code block for some reason)

**Thanks!**

**Edit for the possible duplication**
The reason this isn't a duplicate to that question is because I simply had mistakes in my code that caused these errors. and my controller was already parsing an object.

so it wasn't the problem that my `doc` was not an object; because it was.

Comment: Replace `return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` with `return Json(events, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. You don't need to serialize it beforehand - `Json()` does that for you. As of now - you have your events kind of double converted to json. So on client you have _string_ with json inside, not json object\array.

Comment: then that takes me back to an error I had before. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: at position 0. sorry didnt copy paste it fully

Comment: I eddited the question, check the fiddle

Comment: No I mean on which line in your js script? Just remove everything from your success callback, leave only `var events = []; $.each(doc, ...)`, no need to parse anything.

Comment: oh excuse me, it gives the error on the index: 1.

Comment: That doesn't help :) You have some javascript error. It happens when you execute some javascript statement (such as `var obj = JSON.parse(doc);` or `$.each()` or something else. So which is that javascript statement producing error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165628/discussion-between-fllnangl-and-evk).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269461/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-length-in)

Comment: that's nothing like this one. we solved it in the chat, though I'm getting a new warning. since it was parsing an object. the problem was in the `events: function(start, end, callback)`

Comment: @Evk if you want you can put an answer about the `events function` that I was missing an argument to close this thread iwth an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Evk's help we discovered that I was missing an argument in

`events: function(start, end, callback)`

It should have been

`events: function(start, end, timezone, callback)`

also `var obj = JSON.parse(doc);` is now `var obj = doc;` since that caused it to try and make an object out of an object

and finally in my controller the script below was causing double serialization.

```
// Serialize to JSON string.
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    String json = jss.Serialize(events);
    Debug.WriteLine("Json:"+json);
    return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

removing the serialize and changing it to `return Json(events, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` fixed the errros.

since Evk hasn't posted an answer, I have.

Thanks Evk!

Answer (score 0):

In Operator can be only applied with object. Not with string or primitive type.

Comment: yeah sorry I accidently had the wrong line. it's an object now and I still get the same error. I also edited the question